# Is there a way to make files with an increasing hex name from 00x00 and ending at FFxFF

Tags: python

I have to make a file and give it a name as said in the title and store it. It is part of a 256x256 grid so that’s why it ends at ffxff.

I can’t get my head round how to do it as I’m not too experienced yet. Maybe it has to be a repeating function but I just need a point in the right direction / a chunk or an example to manipulate and understand

Comment: Nested `for` loops should work. The outer loop for the left side number and the inner loop for the right side.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: May be a better way to do this, but `filenames=[hex(y+1).split('x')[1] + ':' + hex(x+1).split('x')[1] for x in range(255) for y in range(255)]` should get you in the ballpark.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, simple [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) do the trick

```py
for row in range(256):
    for col in range(256):
        filename =  f"{row:02X}x{col:02X}"
```

Comment: how about if i wanted to start at 00x00 and increment it by 1 each time in a function but also while creating a file, how would I go about doing that

Comment: @Dec your problem statement is too vague to give a meaningful answer. If you add an outline of your program to the question, it might be clearer. In general, you just keep the `row` and `col` counters somewhere and increment them as required.

Answer (score 0):

This should create the files for you as it loops - just adjust the path accordingly

```
for hi in range(256):
    for lo in range(256):
        open(f'files/{hi:02x}x{lo:02x}', 'w').close()
print('DONE')  # totally optional...
```